# Is there a way I can make my webview scrolling smoother?

Tags: flutter, scrollview, webview-flutter

```
            PageView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: [
               StatefulPageview(  //Displays vertical pageview
                        articles: state.articles,
                        currentPage: currentStare);
                  
               ArticleWebView(  //Displays webview
                      url: 'www.google.com',
                    );
              ],
            );
```

Here I have nested Pageview. Outer one that scrolls horizontally and an inner one that scrolls vertically. The inner pageview works fine but when I swipe right and on the WebView that has to scroll vertically as well, even the slightest horizontal movement scrolls back to the inner Pageview.So i can not basically scroll smoothly inside webview widget.
I even tried creating custom scroll physics to make it work like this.

```
      class StickyPageViewScrollPhysics extends PageScrollPhysics {
         const StickyPageViewScrollPhysics({ScrollPhysics? parent})
          : super(parent: parent);

       @override
       StickyPageViewScrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics? ancestor) {
        return StickyPageViewScrollPhysics(parent: buildParent(ancestor)!);
        }

      @override
       SpringDescription get spring => const SpringDescription(
      mass: 100, 
      stiffness: 1000,
      damping: 10.0, 
    );
    }
```

But it does not seem to work. Does anyone have an idea how can I solve this ?